# How to change the default WindowsPhone 8 calendar

Tags: c#, sdk, calendar, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I know that there is restriction to some parts of **windowsphone core**, and I completely understad that why these limitations setted. But As a corollary of my **locale needs**, I have to change the default calendar into **Jalali (Persian) calendar**.

Up until now, there are different application that provide a simple or complicated **Jalali calendar**, but none of them can **change the internal calendar of windowsPhone 8**.

Its change help us **having Jalali calendar in all applications** so I want to know thet **Is it possible to change the default WindowsPhone 8 calendar to my local calendar?**

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. The Windows Phone APIs do not provide this level of interaction with the system.

Comment: But, do you have an idea, how to ditch the API. for example how to provide a service which all application use it to read the Date?

Comment: @NasserHadjloo As far as I know, the only inter-application interactions available are: registering a specific file extension, and registering a specific URL scheme. None of those provide a solution to your problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused as to what you're asking for here. If you're asking a consumer question please use the appropriate consumer support channels for that (http://support.microsoft.com, http://www.nokia.com/global/support/, etc). I'll continue answering assuming you've asked a developer question.

1. You cannot change the OS Date, Time or Region settings from an app. You might be able to launch some Settings screens, but that's pretty much it.
2. You can use "Calenders" from System.Globalization in your app to allow for non-Gregorian calender flexibility. You can read more about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x.aspx). For example, [HijriCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class should provide you with sufficient localized data. Unfortunately, the [PersianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class isn't supported on WP7/WP8 as it was added in Silverlight 5 and WP7/WP8 is based on Silverlight 4. Feel free to open a [uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform) suggestion that this class be supported in future versions.

Comment: As I said I know that there are restrictions on some settings, and I mentioned that we have a lot of applications which supports **Hijri Calendar**, Still there are many usefull system applications which are using default system **Georgia Date** for example SMS, notification and may more, For those who do not use Georgian date as their default calendar, it's a pain in the neck so I am looking for a solution to solve this issue and provide Hijri Date for all application installed on the phone. And I'm sure it's a developer question, isn't it?